# clean up a wolfram response using xpath , in a java program

Tags: java, xpath, wolfram-mathematica

trying to clean up a response from xpath to get rid of the xml

I have it working fine when I declare the string as follows

```
    String xml = "<section><title>Result</title><sectioncontents>2:58:37 am GMT/IST  |  Friday, December 6, 2013</sectioncontents></section>";
```

but when i declare it as

```
    String response = WOLFRAM_ALPHA.query(s1);
```

i get the following error

```
[Fatal Error] :1:103: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:247)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:287)
    at haha.main(haha.java:53)
```

String xml = "Result2:58:37 am GMT/IST  |  Friday, December 6, 2013";

This works

```
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(source);

    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    String msg = xpath.evaluate("/section/title", document);
    String status = xpath.evaluate("/section/sectioncontents", document);

    System.out.println("msg=" + msg + ";" + "status=" + status);
```

this doesn't

```
    WolframAlpha WOLFRAM_ALPHA = new WolframAlpha("L9PLQU-4L*****URY9");

    // declare the scanner
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            //prompt the user to ask a question
            System.out.println("Please enter a query for wolfram");
            //read in the question and store it in string s1
            String s1 = input.nextLine();   


    String response = WOLFRAM_ALPHA.query(s1);

    System.out.println(response);
    InputSource res = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(res);

    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    String msg = xpath.evaluate("/section/title", document);

    System.out.println(msg);
```

Comment: this is the one that works

Comment: String xml = "<section><title>Result</title><sectioncontents>2:58:37 am GMT/IST  |  Friday, December 6, 2013</sectioncontents></section>";
InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document document = db.parse(source);XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

Comment: XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
String msg = xpath.evaluate("/section/title", document);
     String status = xpath.evaluate("/section/sectioncontents", document);System.out.println("msg=" + msg + ";" + "status=" + status);

Comment: when i change the string to the w/f reponse i get the error , i have it working printing out the whole xml fine from w/f with all the xml

Comment: Please incorporate the information in the above comments into the question via the "edit" link, and make it clear what works and what fails.  Also define `s1`. Thanks.